# How to get the bmp extension files through the intent - Android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, bmp

I want to pick the images with the extension "bmp" through the intent. I have tried passsing the "image/bmp" but it didn't worked. So what's the working way to get the "bmp" extension images through the intent.

Comment: I see no intent.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it into a string.  First you need to convert the file to a .jpg or .png file, (you will have to do this manually outside of code), then convert to bitmap:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( PathToFileString );
```

or

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor( fileDescriptorObject );
```

then

```
fun encode(imageUri: Uri): String {
    val input = activity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri)
    val image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input , null, null)

    // Encode image to base64 string
    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)
    var imageBytes = baos.toByteArray()
    val imageString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT)
    return imageString
 }

fun decode(imageString: String) {

    // Decode base64 string to image
    val imageBytes = Base64.decode(imageString, Base64.DEFAULT)
    val decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, 
    imageBytes.size)

    imageview.setImageBitmap(decodedImage)
}
```

Once you have your string, then put it into an intent:

```
val intent = Intent(this, YourClass::class.java)
intent.putExtra("image", yourString);
startActivity(intent)
```